# Is there a word for a positive outcome borne of a negative (or destructive) intention?

Tags: single-word-requests

Colloquially this is referred to as a "silver lining" but I'm wondering if there's a single word that describes the phenomenon of gleaning positive results from otherwise negative actions/behaviours.

So an example of usage would be "The tornado rampaged through town, but the [my_word] side-effect was that it pulled up all the rotting trees at the end of our street".

Comment: What's wrong with "silver lining"?

Comment: Do you mean you want an adjective like *beneficial*?

Comment: @JasonBassford, precisely but more uniquely tailored to the phenomenon of unintended positive side-effects from an otherwise negative (or negatively intended) action. e.g. "St.Maarten was ravaged by hurricane Irma in 2017 but the [missing word] effect was a massive boost to its economy arising from abundant reconstruction dollars flowing from Holland and France."

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Does it have to be an adjective or can it be a noun? Must it also include the sense of *unintended* in the single word? (To be clear, I can think of a single word that would fit *but the [word] was*. However, *side effect* would be dropped.)